# Musician siblings

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   2. Oddly whirl below a flower (10)
>   8. Oddly drawn 6 down actor (3)
>   10. Revive new line with venerable leaders (7)
>   11. 6 down protects Hong Kong film director (3)
>   12. Elite school leaders' gathering missing total (3, abbr.)
>   15. In Tibet, Rothschilds promise to marry (7)
>   16. US President went after secrets (4)
>   17. Tall Australian coming from East Midlands' number one university (3)
>   19. A certain Albert briefly left by himself (3)
>   23. Legislation of Wales troubled after last bit of justice is lost (4)
>   25. 26 down actor is kind of blueish (7)
>   27. Put music performance's scenery to prearranged position (3)
>   29. City with a famous church and some beautiful mountains (3)
>   30. Marx accepts silver for setting in 16/7 down (7)
>   31. Currency recalled immediately (3)
>   32. 6 and 26 down wore these before girls performed a song (10)
>
> **Down**
>   1. A crazy retired man (4)
>   3. Unopened pieces of medicine for ailments (4)
>   4. Singer Gardner accompanied by body odour, getting behind line to washbasin (6)
>   5. Prominent world leader's victories not recalled (7)
>   6. Leading characters of Elijah Wood making one of 16/7 down (6)
>   7. *(See 16)*
>   9. Less than a dozen left after taxes (3)
>   13. George's brother's organization involved in The Troubles (3)
>   14. Native American tribe seen at the end of autoroute (3)
>   16/7. During The Troubles, police officers captured Ulster extremist group (3,5,8)
>   18. Ms. Lucia reinterpreted 16/7 down, perhaps (7)
>   20. LOTR's first film's final part, following introduction of Elijah Wood (3)
>   21. Wild Llama – new name of musician siblings (6)
>   22. A famous star is not funny in audition (6)
>   24. Not large at all, we heard (3)
>   26. One of 16/7 down is a turkey? (4)
>   27. Imprisoned by his only child (3)
>   28. Spirit's last to possess populated place (4)

Comment: Wait, what?!  jafe's cryptic crossword??  Is it Friday already?!  (Checks calendar...)  Sigh...  Darnit jafe!!

Comment: @Stiv Hehe, just keeping you guys on your toes! There's a lot of printer's devilry in next Friday's crossword, so this one is for those who prefer regular cryptics.

Comment: ...which will only be posted after the weekend, because like a donkey I forgot to post the next puzzle this morning before leaving on my trip. D'oh!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Wordplay explanations:

> 2a. WHIRLBELOW*. 8a. D(-r)A(-w)N. 10a. (LINE+VEN(-erable))*.
>  11a substring of 6d. 12a. SUMMIT minus SUM. 15a. substring. 16a. substring.
>  17a. E(-ast) M(-idlands) U(-niversity). 19a. ALONE minus AL. 23a. *WAL(-e)S)*.
>  25a. BLUEISH*. 27a. quadruple def. 29a. substring. 30a. AG in CHICO. 31a. WON<.
>  32a. SUN + GLASSES.
>  1d. A + MAD<. 3d. (-p)ILLS. 4d. AVA + BO after L. 5d. WINS + TON<.
>  6d. EL(-ijah) + WOOD. 9d. I guess TEN<, though "left" for a *down* clue is odd.
>  13d. Brother of George Gershwin. 14d. (-autoro)UTE.
>  16/7d. THE BOTHERS containing BLUES, containing (-ulste)R.
>  18d. MSLUCIA*. 20d. L(-otr) + (-fil)M after E(-lijah). 21d. (LLAMA N)*.
>  22d. homophone. 24d. homophone. 26d double def. 27d. substring. 28d. T + OWN.